# How to use strptime to extract local dates?

Tags: python, strptime

I am given datetimes recorded in `America/Chicago` in `%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p` format (i.e. `06/18/2019 09:30:00 PM`).
How can I transform these to `datetime` objects that recognise the local timezone/DST?

I tried `datetime.strptime('06/18/2019 09:30:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').astimezone(timezone('America/Chicago'))` which gave unexpected results (i.e. `2019-06-18 21:30:00+01:00` as opposed to `2019-06-18 21:30:00-05:00`).

I was contemplating to augment the string (i.e. by adding "EST" or similar to it). This would, however, leave it to me to determine whether DST was in effect at the time or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [datetime.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) method to replace the tzinfo:

```
ex = '06/18/2019 09:30:00 PM'


extracted_datetime = datetime.strptime(ex, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
my_tz = timezone('America/Chicago')

print(extracted_datetime.replace(tzinfo=my_tz))
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_datetime.dst()` returns None if it does not apply or a timedelta object according to the docs. You should be able to use it as a bool.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

```
    if my_datetime.dst():
        my_strtime = my_strtime + " CDT"
```